# Uploading files in Flask with REST and curl

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I'm trying to make small rest webservice, which will be used only by curl query. And I stuck on uploading files. This is my code (probably some of those imports are not needed)

```
#!bin/python

import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request
from flask import Response
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for
from flask import flash
from flask import session as Session

from werkzeug import create_environ
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '~/testUpload/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['xml'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
environ = create_environ('/','127.0.0.1:5000')
response = Response()

SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'

def allowed_file(filename):
    '''
    '''

    return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET','POST'])
def executeUploadFile():
    '''
    '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = SESSION_TYPE
    app.secret_key = 'aaaa'

    app.run(debug=True)
```

And when I'm trying to execute 
    curl -X POST -F "file=@test.xml" "localhost:5000/upload/"

it returns only bad request. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The url should be `localhost:5000/upload`.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Now I have to figure out why it can't find file in UPLOAD_FOLDER. It looks like flask and werkzeug expects that this file already exist there.
Whats more, when I set UPLOAD_FOLDER with absolute path, flask return error that "BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'executeMethod' instead?
"

Comment: Ok, problem with BuildError solved, my mistake.